# How long does Google Play assigns Content Rating?

Tags: google-play

I have create a draft of my Android application on the Google Play Developer Console. I have filled in all the needed information. One of the required steps is "Content Rating". I have filled in the form to automatically assign content rating by Google. It shows "In progress" status for already 3 days. Do I need to provide anything else or should I just wait? How much does it take to assign Content Rating for Google Play application? I have asked Google Support in parallel to this so will update with comment when will receive a reply.

Comment: I have got answer from Google Support. The questionnaire was saved but it had to be separately sent for processing. I presses "Resume" as suggested by Google Support, reviewed questionnaire again and pressed "Apply for rating".

Comment: Hah 2019 and you saved me sitting here for 24 hours wondering what's taking so long, have an upvote - good work

Answer (score -1):

It should be automatic, please confirm if you haven't skipped any question.